# why cant i populate a vector using a pointer to an array of characters?

Tags: c++, stdvector

So for the following code snippet, I have been stepping through the debugger and when I print the value of the memory pointed to by dataPtr, I can see it has values. However, after the loop executes, if I print the value of dataStream, it is all 0's. Any idea why I cannot populate the vector from the pointer?

```
  std::vector<uint8_t>* dataStream = new std::vector<uint8_t>();
  uint8_t* dataPtr = udpPacket->getData();

  for (int i = 0; i < head->m_cb; ++i) {
      dataStream->push_back(*(dataPtr + i));
  }
```

edit: I have attached a screenshot of what is happening to make it clear what I am doing. I am new to c++ so maybe I am debugging this wrong?
[image: screenshot of gdb variable printing]

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] Note: you do not have to use loop to copy data, just initialize vector with range `( dataPtr, dataPtr + head->m_cb )`

Comment: Not necessarily related to your issue, but Is there a reason you're using a pointer to a vector instead of just a vector?

Comment: Im not sure, new to the game here. I thought 'new' returned a pointer to an object?

Comment: If you're new to C++, avoid `new` !  There is no need for manual memory management in normal applications .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, it seems that initializing the vector with a range solved the problem! The solution is to use

```
std::vector<uint8_t>* dataStream = new std::vector<uint8_t>(dataPtr, dataPtr + head->m_cb);
```

rather than a loop to fill the vector